# Preprocessed file still contains preprocessor instructions

Tags: gcc, preprocessor

When I preprocess a C++ file like this:

```
g++ -E source.cpp
```

the preprocessed file still contains a lot of preprocessor instructions like these:

```
# 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
# 367 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h" 1 3 4
```

I don't need them. How can I get a preprocessed file without these instructions?

Comment: This are not preprocessor instructions but line number information

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`-P` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-P). It prevents GCC from creating these line options:

```
g++ -E -P source.cpp
```